Calculate one year back from the 29th February of a year



0
A
B




1
Current Result
Expected Result


2
2024-02-29
2024-02-29


3
2023-03-01
2023-02-28


4
2022-03-01
2022-02-28


5
2021-03-01
2021-02-28


6
2020-03-01
2020-02-29


7
2019-03-01
2019-02-28



I want that Excel calculates one year back based on the date entered in Cell A2. 
So far this worked without any issue when I use this formula:
=DATE(YEAR(A2)-1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))


However, once I have a leap year and the starting date in Cell A2 is February 29th the calculation one year back ends on the first of March as you can see in Column A.
How do I need to change the formula to get the Expected Result as displayed in Column B?

That will be because 2023 was not a leap year so FEB 29 did not exist.

May be you are trying to accomplish something like this:


• Formula used in cell A3
=LET(x, SEQUENCE(5), EDATE(A2+N(MONTH(DATE(YEAR(A2)-x,2,29))=2)-1,-x*12))



The solution works in the case above but in my final version the dates will be in columns not rows. Is there a way to transpose your values to columns?

=LET(x, SEQUENCE(,5), EDATE(A2+N(MONTH(DATE(YEAR(A2)-x,2,29))=2)-1,-x*12))

In case always the last day of the month is needed the solution is this formula:
=EOMONTH(EDATE(A2;-12);0)


What about
=a2-365

Doesn't calculate one year back, but does calculate 365 days back, which is one year.
